# troubleshoot hello world android application sample

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am getting the following error when i run the hello world app on android 2.2 platform

> [2011-08-21 10:08:47 - Emulator] emulator-arm: ../../src/xcb_io.c:249:
>   process_responses: Assertion `(((long) (dpy->last_request_read) -
>   (long) (dpy->request)) <= 0)' failed.
>
> [2011-08-21 10:08:48 - HelloAndroid] emulator-5554 disconnected!
>   Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity activity
>   launch'!

Answer (score 1):

try to clean the project and re-build

Comment: Use de SDK / AVD manager to create a new virtual device if the above does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error a few days ago after installing new updates for the AVD in the Eclipse "Android SDK and AVD Manager" on my pc (OS: Ubuntu 10.04). This stopped the AVD from working with the same error message as you give in the second sentence.

I ended up uninstalling 1) the Eclipse software and the 2) "Android platform and other components" . Then I reinstalling the software. This worked for me.

I am not sure if this will help you solve the problem, perhaps you have already done the same?